# ASP.NET RadioButtonList Deselecting

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radiobuttonlist:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSwitch1" runat="server" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="rblSwitch1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    style="margin-left: 0px" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">New Shipment</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Existing Shipment</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

that for some reason, occasionally like 5 times a day will deselect after it clicked on. I don't what is causing this and have a hard time trying to replication this my self, I just know it is a problem for for the people using my software. How do I change, if I can, to make it so once it is select, it stays that way.

```
    protected void rblSwitch1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }
```

Comment: Are you persisting the selected value on post back?

Comment: @BillyCoover I am not sure what you mean, which I assume means I am not?

Comment: It should be persisted in the ViewState automatically.  Is there any other code that messes with the radio buttons?

Comment: " AutoPostBack="True" " -- Yeah, he's persisting it on postback.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your markup. You need to provide the whole code and more markup to be able to see what might be going on.

Comment: sorry but please rework on your question i am not getting it what i could get is only that you click on radio button to select it and it goes uncheked and that even not often . do you mean this

Comment: @Icarus I have what seems to be a empty SelectedIndexChanged event(which I am about to delete), could that affect it?

Comment: Can you post that code before you delete it?

Comment: That shouldn't affect it if it is doing nothing and is empty.

Comment: is the id `rblSwitch1` referenced anywhere in the code behind? like on page load or another method?

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'rblSwitch1_SelectedIndexChanged' method to make sure it's not re-directing back to this page, or otherwise setting the SelectedValue of rblSwitch1.

Comment: I suspect it's not a re-direct based on his comment "occasionally like 5 times a day". Perhaps a session state issue, or he has some time-based condition that is doing a re-direct or changing the selected value.